# As soon as I get a voice, I want it to be printed on the screen. What should I do?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm coding with Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;. As soon as I get a voice, I want it to be printed on the screen. What should I do?

It's a code that receives the voice and extracts the results according to the word.
I want change to as soon as i get;

```cs
SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("ko-KR"));

                Grammar g = new Grammar("input.xml");
                sre.LoadGrammar(g);

                sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
                sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

Comment: Microsoft Speech Recognition doesn't supports korean. if you wish to do it, I'd recommend to use Kakao Voice API or Google cloud API.

Comment: actually it supports if you use Grammer class. but it allows item which contained only.